# How to handle HTTP/2 GOAWAY with HttpClient?

Tags: java, http2, java-11, java-http-client

I am trying to continuously send GET and POST requests to a REST API every few minutes. The issue is that after exactly 1000 requests I receive a [`GOAWAY`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-6.8) frame (and an `IOException`):

> The GOAWAY frame (type=0x7) is used to initiate shutdown of a connection or to signal serious error conditions.
> <sub>[§ 6.8, RFC 7540](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-6.8)</sub>

---

I did a fair bit of research and found that not only is 1000 requests [nginx's default maximum](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_requests), Cloudfront ([related Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=681477)) and Discord also exhibit the same behavior.

I tried to reproduce this problem with a local nginx server with the default HTTP/2 configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    http2_max_requests 1000;
    ...
}
```

```
var client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .build();

for (var i = 0; i < 1100; i++) {
    var url = URI.create(String.format("https://localhost/images/test%d.jpg", i));

    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(url).build();

    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    System.out.printf("Image %d processed%n", i);
}
```

And after approximately 1000 requests, I get a `GOAWAY` error as expected:

```
...
Image 998 processed
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: /127.0.0.1:49259: GOAWAY received
```

---

My first thought would be to check if the exception message contains the string `"GOAWAY"` and then retry the request accordingly:

```
try {
    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (e.getMessage().contains("GOAWAY")) {
        client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    } else throw e;
}
```

My issue with this approach is that the string comparison seems like it may be fragile. Additionally, since all I have is an IOException with a message, I can't differentiate between `GOAWAY` frames with a genuine error code (in which case I should probably stop sending requests) and those with `NO_ERROR` (in which case I could probably retry the request).

How should I correctly deal with/handle `GOAWAY` errors (apart from using HTTP/1.1 instead)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A server is entitled to close connections at any time, for any reason.

In the HTTP/2 `GOAWAY` frame there is the indication of what was the last stream processed by the server, so the client can know what stream needs to be resent when a connection is closed.

Unfortunately, the `lastStreamId` is not surfaced in `java.net.http.HttpClient`, so there is no way to know it and take appropriate actions.

Your alternative could be to use other clients that support surfacing the `lastStreamId`, or use a lower level HTTP/2 client where you will have the `GOAWAY` frame available and therefore access to the `lastStreamId`.

[Disclaimer, I am the Jetty HTTP/2 implementer]
Jetty supports a lower level HTTP/2 client that you can use for your use case - you may want to give it a try.
You can find an example of how to use Jetty's `HTTP2Client` [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.15.v20190215/jetty-alpn/jetty-alpn-java-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/java/client/JDK9HTTP2Client.java).

Comment: are the streams processed in any particular order? e.g. if lastStreamId=2

Comment: Stream processing order is undefined. Implementations can choose whatever suits them best.

Comment: If you set "jdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log" system property to "requests,channel,headers,errors,frames:all" for example,  then you will be able to see the stream id