# GOAWAY BItBucket API using java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, http, bitbucket, httpclient, java-http-client

Using `java.net.http.HttpClient` to send the request to BitBucket API with the following config:

```
var url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/asomov/snakeyaml/issues/377";

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS)
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .uri(URI.create(url))
                    .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot")
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

The following exception is thrown, always:

```
java.io.IOException: /192.168.1.126:58337: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:576)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /192.168.1.126:58337: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleGoAway(Http2Connection.java:985)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleConnectionFrame(Http2Connection.java:853)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.processFrame(Http2Connection.java:724)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.frame.FramesDecoder.decode(FramesDecoder.java:155)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$FramesController.processReceivedData(Http2Connection.java:232)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.asyncReceive(Http2Connection.java:649)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.processQueue(Http2Connection.java:1275)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.runOrSchedule(Http2Connection.java:1293)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onNext(Http2Connection.java:1319)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onNext(Http2Connection.java:1253)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$DelegateWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:202)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:484)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:287)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run1(SubscriberWrapper.java:318)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run(SubscriberWrapper.java:261)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:234)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:200)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:403)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:264)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Extra info:

- Adding an `Authentication` header with valid credentials as explained [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/example-basic-authentication/#supplying-basic-auth-headers) does not solve the issue
- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087292/how-to-handle-http-2-goaway-with-httpclient) it would seem like I am sending too many request but not even a single one gets through

Comment: I'd suggest switching on logging of request/response headers: it might help you figure out what is going on. You can pass `-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=errors,requests,headers` on the Java command line. It's possible - for instance - that the server requires an `Accept` header indicating which kind of content the client is prepared to accept, or it's possible that this is an authorisation issue, etc... Being able to see which headers are sent and received over the wire might help figuring this out.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably using http/2 (happened to me too). You need to use http/1.1.

Use 'version' method to do that: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#version(java.net.http.HttpClient.Version)

Comment: for me it was true, 1.1 version works perfect.