# GCM (legacy FCM) sends GOAWAY HTTP/2 frames

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, http2

Our push backend uses [GCM API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send notifications to Android devices.
Endpoint: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`
HTTP client: [Java 11 Http Client](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) (with HTTP/2 setting):

```java
var httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
    // ...
    .build();
```

**Problem**
Sometimes we get [`GOAWAY`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.8) frames from GCM. But [java http client hides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55092354) both error-code and payload for those frames (just throws some generic exception). So we don't know what is causing `GOAWAY`.

**Questions**

1. Is it an expected behavior of GCM API?
2. What could cause it?
3. How to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell for sure why GCM sends `GOAWAY` - only the GCM team can really answer this. However some of the usual reasons for it are:

- The server your client is connected to is going down for maintainence. Before doing that it enters a draining mode that allows to complete ongoing requests while preventing new ones. This is achieved by sending a `GOAWAY`  that informs the client that no new requests should be started on that connection.
- The server wants the client to migrate to a different connection for load balancing purposes

That means a server sending a `GOAWAY` is not a bug, it's just something to be expected in a cloud setup.

The HTTP/2 specifciation provides some further information on how to handle `GOAWAY`: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.8

Regarding handling it: Ideally your HTTP/2 client might already do that fully internally:

- if it receives a `GOAWAY` frame while no request is active it should create a new connection for the next request
- if it receives a `GOAWAY` frame while a request has been sent, and if that `GOAWAY` frame indicates the request hasn't been processed, a new client can be created and the request retried. This works even if its a non-idempotent request (like a `POST`), since we know the server hasn't processed the request yet.

If the JDK11 client does not do that automatically, the only thing  you can really do here is retry on application layer.

According to  [is there any way to handle HTTP/2 Goaway received IOException in HttpClient java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018337/is-there-any-way-to-handle-http-2-goaway-received-ioexception-in-httpclient-java) it seems like the client might throw an `IOException` whose message contains `GOAWAY received`. That might be a good signal to retry.