# is there any way to handle HTTP/2 Goaway received IOException in HttpClient java?

Tags: java, http, http2

I am making API calls in the application, At some point randomly it throws `java.io.IOException: /149.222.1.1:553232: GOAWAY received`,
using Java 11 environment.
anyway to resolve this exception rather than moving to Http/1.1 or other HTTP client libraries?

here is the stack trace

```
"com.abcd.common.RequestProcessor:53 getRequest: java.io.IOException: /149.222.1.1:553232: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at com.abcd.common.RequestProcessor.getRequest(RequestProcessor.java:49)
    at com.abcd.common.util.SendApiRequestUtil.sendApiRequestToCMS(SendApiRequestUtil.java:97)
    at com.abcd.controller.ContactsController.getContacts(ContactsController.java:61)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
    at com.abcd.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1292)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /169.254.8.1:55302: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleGoAway(Http2Connection.java:985)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleConnectionFrame(Http2Connection.java:853)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.processFrame(Http2Connection.java:724)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.frame.FramesDecoder.decode(FramesDecoder.java:155)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$FramesController.processReceivedData(Http2Connection.java:232)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.asyncReceive(Http2Connection.java:649)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.processQueue(Http2Connection.java:1275)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.runOrSchedule(Http2Connection.java:1293)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onNext(Http2Connection.java:1319)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onNext(Http2Connection.java:1253)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$DelegateWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:202)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:484)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onNext(SSLTube.java:287)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run1(SubscriberWrapper.java:318)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run(SubscriberWrapper.java:261)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:234)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:200)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:403)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:264)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

Comment: if the server decides to break the connection, switching client libraries won't help in any way.

Answer (score 5):

This is something that your code will just have to deal with.

A GOAWAY frame has been sent by the HTTP 2.0 server that your client is talking to. That means that the server has decided to shut down the connection for some reason. The only thing that the client side can do is tell the caller via an `IOException`.

This is analogous to an HTTP 1.x server doing a TCP reset ... or just disconnecting. These will also result in a client-side `IOException`.

So, the solution is to catch the `IOException` and handle it; e.g. by reporting to the user that the request has failed, or retrying the HTTP request using a fresh connection.

(If you retry, you need some strategy to avoid your client code repeating a request that is never going to succeed. Indeed, ill-advised retrying can actually make things worse, if the reason that the server disconnected is that it is overloaded.)

---

I doubt that switching to HTTP 1.1 would help. I would expect that you would continue to get "random" `IOExceptions` with a different message ... from the server using HTTP 1.1.

---

There were a couple of JDK bugs related to GOAWAY handling in HTTPClient, but they were marked as resolved in 2018. You can use this query to find them:

- [https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198947?jql=text%20~%20%22httpclient%20goaway%22](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198947?jql=text%20%7E%20%22httpclient%20goaway%22)

I don't think they are relevant if you are using the latest version of JDK 11.

Answer (score 4):

try adding ".version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)" in your http request

Comment: But this does not fit with in the OP's requirements of "anyway to resolve this exception rather than moving to Http/1.1".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem with our application. I tested it using three separate server instances (TEST1, TEST2, and Live).

Only the first two environments (TEST1 and TEST2) cause our programme to exhibit the behaviour described above; in the third environment (Live), however, everything functions as it should and we are not receiving the 'GOAWAY received' error.

As a temporary fix, I downgraded the HTTP Client version to 1.1, which resolved the problem in TEST1 and TEST2.

We haven't found the solution yet and are continuously looking into it because different circumstances create varied behaviours.

This conversation on github was really beneficial for me to move on.

**https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/25279**

Java version we are using is - openjdk version "**11.0.21**" 2023-10-17 LTS

We would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that given GOAWAY is send from server to "idle connection after being idle too long". Generally, you can configure to not log such exception if they occur in client holding connection on background.

In your case I see, that exception is thrown from your code:

```
com.abcd.common.RequestProcessor.getRequest(RequestProcessor.java:49)
```

This is not case described at the beginning of my answer.

What is "random point in time"? Is it during http call? Does server wait for longer period of time for your input to be sent?

PS: There is also great chance, that after your 1000th request using single TCP connection, server does close connection. It is a default value for nginx at least. See https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/03/how-to-handle-http2-goaway-with.html for more info.

Comment: Original of the linked resource is [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087292/how-to-handle-http-2-goaway-with-httpclient)